# Collect "prompt" data to use it in an API

Tags: javascript

I created a program to collect weather info from GPS decimal info.
But I cannot succeed in collect prompt data to use it in API.

What is missing?

```
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <title>API METEO</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>METEO</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='temperature'>"temperature"</span> c° (temperature)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='pressure'>"pressure"</span> hpa (pression par rapport au niveau de la mer)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='visibility'>"visibility"</span> km (visibilité horizontale)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='windspeed'>"windspeed"</span> km/h (vitesse du vent)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='winddire'>"winddire"</span> ° (direction du vent)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='clouds'>"clouds"</span> % (couverture nuageuse)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='sunrise'>"sunrise"</span> (Heure du lever du soleil)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='sunset'>"sunset"</span> (Heure du coucher du soleil)
</h2>

<h2>
    <span id='timezone'>"timezone"</span> H GMT Time zone
</h2>

<script>
    var firstnumber = prompt("entrez la latitude");
    var secondnumber = prompt("entrez la longitude")

</script>

<script>

    async function main(){
    const meteo = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='Number(firstnumber)'&lon='Number(secondnumber)'&units=metric&lang=fr&appid=XXX')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json)
    
    console.log(meteo);

    displayWeatherInfos(meteo)
}

    function displayWeatherInfos(data){
    const name = data.name;
    const temperature = data.main.temp;
    const pressure = data.main.pressure;
    const visibility = data.visibility;
    const windspeed = data.wind.speed;
    const winddire = data.wind.deg;
    const windgust = data.wind.gust;
    const clouds = data.clouds.all;
    const sunrise = data.sys.sunrise;
    const sunset = data.sys.sunset;
    const timezone = data.timezone;
    
    document.querySelector('#temperature').textContent = Math.round(temperature);
    document.querySelector('#pressure').textContent = pressure;
    document.querySelector('#visibility').textContent = (visibility/1000);
    document.querySelector('#windspeed').textContent = Math.round(windspeed*3.6);
    document.querySelector('#winddire').textContent = winddire;
    document.querySelector('#clouds').textContent = clouds;
    document.querySelector('#sunrise').textContent = new Date(sunrise*1000).toUTCString(sunrise*1000);
    document.querySelector('#sunset').textContent = new Date(sunset*1000).toUTCString(sunset*1000);
    document.querySelector('#timezone').textContent = timezone/3600;
    
}

main();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I trigger HTML, I can file successively longitude and latitude, but no data is collected from API answer.

Comment: One obvious thing is if you are combining strings and variables, you will want to do something like **' + Number(firstnumber) + '** otherwise in the URL it will be passed as a string

Answer (score 0):

## To debug, changing the central part of the code to this

```
   async function main(){
      
       const url =  'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='Number(firstnumber)'&lon='Number(secondnumber)'&units=metric&lang=fr&appid=XXX';

       console.log("The URL I am looking for is:\n",url)

       const meteo = await fetch(url)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(json => json)

   console.log(meteo);
```

That way you can check that you are looking at a reasonable URL.

## There is a mistake in your expression for the URL

You want the URL to be the concatenation of several strings, so you probably need a "+" between them. I am not sure you really need the `Number()`.

Try:

```
url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + firstnumber + '&lon=' + secondnumber + '&units=metric&lang=fr&appid=XXX'
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, though, so the community knows I have done something useful 8-)